# finding most 'popular' items in multiple tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables of items which are 'ordered' by their ratings/popularity.
I need to combine all the tables into one table with a top 10.
The top 10 will combine the number of times an entry (with wildcard as the names may be slightly different) appears in all the lists and it's position in the tables.
is this possible?
I've researched Joins but it seems quite a complicated procedure given there are two factors (nubmer of entries and position in the tables).

---

Apologies for being vague, I didn't think I was doing so. This is my first question on stackoverflow

```
    table 1 table 2 table 3
--------------------
bob   | bob   | Ian
fred  | james |john
kate  | fred  | bob
mary  | brian | brian
```

the 'rankings' results of the three tables need to appear in a final table (called 'final' for example)
As you can see Bob would rank highly on 'final'.
But Ian appears only once, even though he is top of the list in table 3.
Fred appears in position 2 and position 3 so should he be higher or lower than Ian.
would I need an algorithm for the sorting or is there some trick in mySQl that will examine the rankings?

Comment: This is all way too vague

Comment: This is too vague for SO. No data structure, no info on what you have tried (if you tried something). Please read the FAQ and post more specific questions.

Comment: It's possible, but you need to work out exactly what needs to happen. Seeing as you have two criteria, you are going to need some kind of points system and sort the final table based on that.

Comment: Post the table declares, some sample data and what you want to return from that sample data please.

Comment: You need to define how to rank them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return them with a ranking, but you need to define how that rank applies.

For example if you just return the ranking from each table then Bob appears twice in the first position. If you add those 2 ranks together it gives 2. How do you compare that to Ian who is only ranked 1 once.

For this you are probably best building a ranking from the last row (or calculating it as total number of rows - ranking).

You can get a basic ranking from each table with the following:-

```
SELECT some_name, @rank_1:=@rank_1 + 1 AS ranking
FROM table_1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank_1:=0) sub_1
UNION ALL
SELECT some_name, @rank_2:=@rank_2 + 1 AS ranking
FROM table_2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank_2:=0) sub_2
UNION ALL
SELECT some_name, @rank_2:=@rank_2 + 1 AS ranking
FROM table_2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank_2:=0) sub_3
```

but this will give you each record from each table and their ranking.

As it is though, you have nothing to say that Bob is the first record on table_1. While it may be the first record, as far as the order returned this is not a certainty.